# How to add custom options and buttons in wordpress MCE Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-theming

I am developing a premium Wordpress theme [first time :)] and I want to know how to add custom buttons and options into the `Tiny MCE Editor`.

Like other premium themes they provide a custom button and a popup div area for custom options (may be a simple div), I also want to do so. I want the functions that can do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great tutorial for adding custom button to Tiny MCE editor: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/wordpress-shortcodes-the-right-way/

You can try this plugin also: [**Ultimate TinyMCE**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/)

WordPress Codex Reference: [TinyMCE Custom Buttons](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons)